# How do I get the most recent call of a command, and save it in a function?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've been messing with bots for a couple days now, and I'm trying to get the name of the user that called a certain command, then be able to use that later on in a different command. I've tried using context.author, as in the example below, but it doesn't seem to work.

```py
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@client.command()
async def help(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Test string")
    variable = context.user  
    #variable is updated each time help function is called

@client.command()
async def get_user(ctx):
    await ctx.send(variable)
```

Comment: Do you have code that illustrates what you're trying to do? Or could you create a sample session that shows how the command would work?

Comment: okay i added some sample code

Comment: Firstly `await` doesn't work without `async def`. `variable` is something from global scope, right?

Comment: sorry i left that out, i updated it to all the needed code that's being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a global variable.

```
variable = ""

@client.command()
async def help(ctx):
    global variable
    await ctx.send("Test string")
    variable = str(ctx.author.name)

@client.command()
async def get_user(ctx):
    global variable
    await ctx.send(variable)
```

Comment: This throws the error that: 'Context' object has no attribute 'user'.

Comment: It should be `ctx.author.name`

Comment: Ah yes, sorry for that. I must have been in a rush!